# Convert video to OGV, on fedora platform

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fedora, rhel

I need to develop a rest API for publishing and converting videos.

A major hurdle that I am facing, I need a free converter to convert video in any format to
OGV. Even though ffmpeg is the best candidate, but I cannot use it because it is not
in official Fedora repository, but in rpmfusion. I am developing a product that would be deployed on Fedora infra, they only deploy applications via packages into epel6.

Can you guys suggest something from the official fedora repository ?

Comment: maybe create your own package? libav?

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any package which provides non-free (read: patent encumbered) video encoders and decoders in the official Fedora repositories, see [1] and [2].

- [1] https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Software_Patents
- [2] https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items